# Failed to send event to MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, logstash

I am using logstash to collect data from android device using http-poller as input plugin. I want to store the collected data in a NoSQL(mongodb) using mongodb as output plugin. I have successfully set up the configuration file but when I run my set-up, I get the following error:

> Failed to send event to MongoDB {:event=>#, @cancelled=false, @data={"error"=>501, "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2016-10-03T18:02:11.337Z", "http_poller_metadata"=>{"name"=>"some_other_service", "host"=>"s18660276.domainepardefaut.fr", "request"=>{"method"=>"post", "url"=>"http://127.0.0.1/web/app.php/api/addsmartlog"}, "runtime_seconds"=>0.526, "code"=>200, "response_headers"=>{"date"=>"Mon, 03 Oct 2016 18:02:11 GMT", "server"=>"Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)", "x-powered-by"=>"PHP/5.5.30-1~dotdeb+7.1", "cache-control"=>"no-cache", "content-length"=>"13", "keep-alive"=>"timeout=5, max=100", "connection"=>"Keep-Alive", "content-type"=>"application/json"}, "response_message"=>"OK", "times_retried"=>0}}, @metadata={}, @accessors=#501, "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2016-10-03T18:02:11.337Z", "http_poller_metadata"=>{"name"=>"some_other_service", "host"=>"s18660276.domainepardefaut.fr", "request"=>{"method"=>"post", "url"=>"http://127.0.0.1/web/app.php/api/addsmartlog"}, "runtime_seconds"=>0.526, "code"=>200, "response_headers"=>{"date"=>"Mon, 03 Oct 2016 18:02:11 GMT", "server"=>"Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)", "x-powered-by"=>"PHP/5.5.30-1~dotdeb+7.1", "cache-control"=>"no-cache", "content-length"=>"13", "keep-alive"=>"timeout=5, max=100", "connection"=>"Keep-Alive", "content-type"=>"application/json"}, "response_message"=>"OK", "times_retried"=>0}}, @lut={"http_poller_metadata"=>[{"error"=>501, "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2016-10-03T18:02:11.337Z", "http_poller_metadata"=>{"name"=>"some_other_service", "host"=>"s18660276.domainepardefaut.fr", "request"=>{"method"=>"post",  "@timestamp"=>"2016-10-03T18:02:11.337Z", "http_poller_metadata"=>{"name"=>"some_other_service", "host"=>"s18660276.domainepardefaut.fr", "request"=> "runtime_seconds"=>0.526, "code"=>200, "response_headers"=>{"date"=>"Mon, 03 Oct 2016 18:02:11 GMT", "server"=>"Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)", "x-powered-by"=>"PHP/5.5.30-1~dotdeb+7.1", "cache-control"=>"no-cache", "content-length"=>"13", "keep-alive"=>"timeout=5, max=100", "connection"=>"Keep-Alive", "content-type"=>"application/json"}, "response_message"=>"OK", "times_retried"=>0}}, "@timestamp"]}>>, :exception=>#"admin"}, @server_selection_timeout=30>>, :backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/server_selector/selectable.rb:99:in `select_server'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/cluster.rb:122:in`next_primary'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/collection.rb:190:in `insert_many'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/mongo-2.0.6/lib/mongo/collection.rb:175:in`insert_one'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-mongodb-2.0.5/lib/logstash/outputs/mongodb.rb:56:in `receive'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:109:in`multi_receive'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:109:in`multi_receive'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:130:in `worker_multi_receive'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:114:in`multi_receive'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:301:in `output_batch'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in`each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:301:in `output_batch'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:232:in`worker_loop'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:201:in `start_workers'"], :level=>:warn}
>       ^CSIGINT received. Shutting down the agent. {:level=>:warn}

Can anyone help out?

Comment: Have you check that the server running logstash can "talk" to your mongodb?